# Unable to switch GitHub account in VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am trying to switch to my personal account on my company laptop and for some reason I still am unable to have access to my personal GitHub repo.

- I have changed the git config settings (username and email).
- I've changed the settings in VS Code (git config is in sync with Personal and I can see my personal GitHub on the bottom left of the ID when I click the avatar.
- I've tried manually creating different keys and an ssh config following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) tutorial

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried creating a new repo and pushing to it but I still get the same message: `ERROR: Permission to macro6461/changelog-bash-script.git denied to companyGHusername.`

Where do I need to change the GitHub user? I feel like I've changed it everywhere I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Tbh. i'm not sure on which stack vs-code works with git & credentials. I can just tell you, that Git for Windows stores authentication information within the windows credentials. I can't find the english name for it currently, in German its "Ameldeinformationsverwaltung", earlier i found it once as "Windows-Tresor". Maybe you can find there some credentials to delete?

(Assuming you're on windows.)

Greets,
Jonas

Comment: It was actually very dumb. I didn't have an SSH on my personal github. Once I added that I was able to push. I am still not clear on how to better switch between profiles but for now this works.